# How to merge two data frames with different lengths by recycling without duplication in R?

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

Suppose we've got two data frames and we want to merge them. The number of values of each group in `df2` is less than or equal to the number of values in `df1`:

```
df1 <- data.frame(group = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 4), rep("C", 2)),
                  values = c(51, 13, 18, 89, 3, 27, 86, 85, 31, 100, 55))
df2 <- data.frame(group = c(rep("A", 2), rep("B", 2), rep("C", 2)),
                  values = c(30, 36, 50, 60, 45, 70))
df.merge <- merge(df1, df2, "group")
```

We get something like this:

```
head(df1)
## group values
## A     51
## A     13
## A     18
## A     89
## A      3
## B     27

df2
## group values
## A     30
## A     36
## B     50
## B     60
## C     45
## C     70

head(df.merge)
## group values.x values.y
## A       51       30
## A       51       36
## A       13       30
## A       13       36
## A       18       30
## A       18       36
```

So for each unique `value` of `df2`, each row of the corresponding group in `df1` is duplicated.

My aim is to get:

```
## group values.x values.y
## A       51       30
## A       13       36
## A       18       30
## A       89       36
## A        3       30
## B       27       50
## B       86       60
## B       85       50
## B       31       60
## C       100      45
## C       55       70
```

Is there any convenient way to achieve this?

Comment: I'd appreciate being told the reason for the downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This'll do it:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 = data.table(df1)
dt2 = data.table(df2)

setkey(dt2, group)

dt1[, values.y := dt2[J(.BY[[1]])]$values, by = group]
dt1
#    group values values.y
# 1:     A     51       30
# 2:     A     13       36
# 3:     A     18       30
# 4:     A     89       36
# 5:     A      3       30
# 6:     B     27       50
# 7:     B     86       60
# 8:     B     85       50
# 9:     B     31       60
#10:     C    100       45
#11:     C     55       70
```

Comment: +1 Beat my (deleted) answer by a minute. I'm surprised that didn't give a warning about recycling. It's also possible to write it as `dt1[, values.y := dt2[.(g)]$values, by =list(g=group)]`...which I like the look of better.

Comment: @Frank I think the absence of a warning is a bug

Comment: bug report added - https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=4990&group_id=240&atid=975

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would have thought that `.BY[[1]]` only returns the first entry within the group rather than all entries. On the other hand, `by` has only one argument here, so why isn't it possible to write `dt1[, values.y := dt2[J(.BY)]$values, by = group]`? Is `.BY` always a list that has to be subsetted?

Comment: @Frank Thanks for the suggestion! Why isn't it possible to write `dt1[, values.y := dt2[.(group)]$values, by = group]`?

Comment: I didn't try it, but I'm guessing that it would not work because dt2 also has a group column, which would be grabbed instead of the dt1 group associated with the `by=group`. Also, yes, .BY is always a list.

Comment: just to be clear what `.BY` is, if you had `by =list(col1, col2)`, the first element would be the value of `col1` in the current group, and the second the value of `col2`

Answer (score 1):

A solution using base R.  Essentially the idea is to repeat the values for each group in `df2` to equal the number of rows in each group in `df1`.  This can be done with `rep` and the argument `length.out`.  It can be done separately for each group in `by`, and then I just `unlist` to a vector to add to `df1`

```
df1$values.y = unlist(by(df2, df2$group, 
                    function(x) rep(x$values, length.out = length(df1$group[df1$group == x$group]))))
```

Comment: Thanks! I was also thinking about repeating, but my solution wasn't as neat as yours.